# Display custom post using ID

Tags: wordpress

In my theme, I have a custom post type called sliders. Here the user is allowed to upload images in a `meta-box`. So, the images are saved as meta data in `wp_post_meta` table.

Now what I want to do is, displaying a slider using its ID.

I did like following but no result

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=sliders&p=411');

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
   while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
   the_post();
 endwhile;
}
```

This doesn't display anything. No even errors. Anyway, If I used `the_title()` instead of `the_post()`, it shows the title of the slider fine. Same for the `the_author()` It shows the author without error.

Why is this weird ?

Answer (score 0):

According to **Codex**  `the_post();` :

> `the_post();`  iterate the post index in The Loop. Retrieves the next
>   post, sets up the post, sets the 'in the loop' property to true.
>   **This function does not return any values.**

Example for how we use this function:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {

        the_post();

        he_title();

        the_content();

    }
}
?>
```

You didn't explain well you question. anyway to display your metabox just use API function

```
echo get_post_meta( $id, 'metabox_name', true );
```